# Convert latitude longitude to x,y point on a rectangle

Tags: algorithm, math, latitude-longitude

It seems that there are lots of information both in Google and here, that speak a lot about many different conversions of latitude,longitude.

So what i'm asking is for you to be simple as possible, and try not sending me to other places to seek an answer.

I am trying to put the entire world in to 2D square, where each point represent the distance(in meters) from a point which I choose to define it `(0,0)`,
Can you give me a mathematical algorithm to do so.

Comment: It depends entirely on the map projection you use. That's why there are so many algorithms.

Comment: What are your accuracy requirements?  If you don't care about accuracy, the simplest solution is x = lon; y = lat.

Comment: can you clarify the last paragraph?  it's not clear to me what you mean or want.  a point represents a distance?

Answer (score 1):

You could either use a [**azimuthal equidistant**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuthal_equidistant_projection) or [**two-point equidistant**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-point_equidistant_projection) projection.

Of these the **azimuthal equidistant** is easiest.  To do this, just start at your reference point on the world, and put this in the center of your map.  Then proceed outward in concentric circles on the map, and for each new circle plot all the points on the world at the appropriate distance and angle.

After doing this, your map should look like a circle, and all of the points will be the correct distance from your center point.